# home's vs homes'

Tags: grammar

When referring to the homes decor would it be homes' or home's?

Example: The custom design can blend seamlessly with the homes' (or home's) decor.

2nd Example: We offer custom interior finishes that can match the homes' (or home's) interior.

Comment: Strictly speaking it depends on *context* (whether the speaker is talking about a "decor, interior" that's common to some contextually-known group of multiple homes, or just ***one specific home***). But for all practical purposes (also noting that this is just an orthographic feature that isn't reflected in speech anyway), you should probably just assume ***home's*** is "correct".

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, "home's", in this context, would be correct when you are referring to a specific home, or to homes in general.

> Triple-glazed windows will make the home's interior much more comfortable in the winter.  (Dealing with a general home here; it would also be correct to use "homes' interiors".)
>
> A customer can bring us ideas on how she wants to decorate her dwelling.  We offer custom interior finishes that can match the home's interior.  (Clearly dealing with a specific home here)

If you are specifically referring to multiple homes, use "homes'":

> She wants both residences redecorated, which will considerably improve the homes' charm.

If you used "homes'" in your first example, it ought to be modified to be syntactically consistent:

> The custom designs can blend seamlessly with the homes' decors.  (Each home has an individual design, and each home has its own decor.)

Answer (score 0):

As you known, home's is singular possessive, and homes' is plural possessive.

> The home's front door.
>
> The homes' front doors.

*Decor* is usually an uncountable noun, so "homes' decor" is fine.  In this context it's not clear if you want to talk about one home or multiple homes, so I can't say for certain which you want to use.

Regardless, it would be more common to use *home decor* as a compound noun.

> We offer custom designs that match with any/your **home decor**.